# proper way of handling multiple user type in django 1.10

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-allauth

I have researched a bit in the google and found out many different solutions for handling multiple user type. To make my question more clear, here is the requirement

1) There is two types of user - (one is general and another is developer)

2) Both user types will have same form field - (username, email, password, password(confirm))

The below is what I have tried.

```
class customUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_choice = (
        ('G', 'General'),
        ('D', 'Developer'),
    )
    user_type = models.charField(choices=user_choices, max_length=2, default='G')

class mainUser(customUser):
    type = models.OneToOneField('customUser')
```

Do I have to handle explicitly for username, email, password and re-password field?

I am using django allauth for single user registration and login. Do I have to now work it differently?

Comment: Based on what you're sharing, it seems like you'd be much better off just using a `Profile` model: see [Extending the `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: Do you actually need to build a custom user type? Maybe just adding a model linked to the standard `User` model would be enough, unless you need some special logic. From what you're describing here, it doesn't look like you need to have different models.

Comment: @LaurentS can you show me a rough code on creating two different user? The user will have option to select sign up process. The option is signup as developer and signup as normal user as stated above. Not building signup in custom way.

Comment: @pythonLover what is the difference between the types of users? do you need to store different information in their profiles, or is the type just going to trigger differences in views and such?

Comment: just the difference in view.

Comment: Is showing just badge of developer or general user comes into profile? The main purpose of separating the user is to show the content accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is different logic in views, I'd do what Jens suggests in the comments. Extend the base `User` model with a `Profile`, something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_choice = (
        ('G', 'General'),
        ('D', 'Developer'),
    )
    user_type = models.charField(choices=user_choices, max_length=2, default='G')
```

Then either add a way to select `user_type` at signup, or just provide 2 different views to signup.

And in your views, where you need logic that depends on account type:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.user.profile.user_type == 'G':
         # do stuff for General users
    else:
         # do Developer stuff
```

Comment: Do I have to create a different signup form view for both developer and general?

Comment: That's your design decision. I don't think there is any reason why you *have* to. You can probably just subclass the standard signup form, and add an input to choose what account type the user wants.